# getimagesize() error: "failed to open stream: No such file or directory" even though the file exists

Tags: php

I'm trying to get image width and height from a jpg file extracted from PDF file using code:

```
if (file_exists($firstPagePath)) {
    if (is_readable($firstPagePath)) {
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($firstPagePath);
    }
}
```

I have confirmed that it is correct image by running command line identify:

```
JPEG 1190x1684 1190x1684+0+0 8-bit sRGB 192302B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

File exists and it is readable but still it throws failed to open stream: No such file or directory error. I have already checked [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory) but it didn't helped. I'm looking for any idea...

Comment: Can you confirm that the file is local, and that you aren’t using any stream wrappers?

Comment: We can confirm that the file is local on the server where PHP process has full access rights.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have and the full complete error message you get from the execution of your PHP script. Also add a `var_dump(firstPagePath);` before the line you call `getimagesize()` (but still inside the `if()` block).

Answer (score 0):

Caution from [`getimagesize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php).

> This function expects filename to be a valid image file. If a non-image file is supplied, it may be incorrectly detected as an image and the function will return successfully, but the array may contain nonsensical values.
>
> Do not use getimagesize() to check that a given file is a valid image. Use a purpose-built solution such as the Fileinfo extension instead.

In case that the file is not an image it will be `false` anyway.

Use `finfo()` class to check the file must be image.

```php
$finfo = new finfo();

if (is_file($firstPagePath) && stripos($finfo->file($firstPagePath, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE), 'image/') !== false) {
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($firstPagePath);
    var_dump($width);
    var_dump($height);
}
```

Note that `file_exists()` can check both folder and file if in the same name. Use `is_file()` to make sure that it is file and must be exists.

Use `$finfo->file($firstPagePath, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE)` to retreive file's mime type and check with `stripos()` that it must be `image/xxx` for example `image/jpeg`.

You can use the `$finfo->file()` as shown above to echo out and see that what is your file's mime type.

Comment: The file is definitely an image.

Comment: Yes, sure. it is definitely an image but let's see your file's mime type. `$finfo = new finfo();` and then `echo $finfo->file($firstPagePath, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);` will be show the result from PHP that what is your file'e mime type. And try `var_dump(is_file(firstPagePath));` to debug that you file is really exists.